# MongoDB projection in elixir returning error

Tags: mongodb, elixir, phoenix-framework

I used this https://github.com/ankhers/mongodb driver to run queries on my 
Elixir application.

The doc specifies that the `Mongo.find(...)` function returns specified fields with `projection` option. But, when I try to pass the required field in projection, I get the following error:

> ** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Enumerable not implemented for "ques_text". This protocol is implemented for:
>   DBConnection.PrepareStream, DBConnection.Stream, Date.Range,
>   Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Stream, File.Stream, Function, GenEvent.Stream,
>   HashDict, HashSet, IO.Stream, List, Map, MapSet,
>   Mongo.AggregationCursor, Mongo.Cursor, Mongo.SinglyCursor,
>   Postgrex.Stream, Range, Stream, Timex.Interval

My query looks like this:

> Mongo.find(:mongo, "questions", %{"no_of_options": 4}, [projection:
>   "ques_text", limit: 1])

And I can see the `ques_text` field under `select` field of `%Mongo.Cursor`.

Is that a wrong way to pass projection option? I am new to Elixir.

Comment: Can you try this: `[projection: %{"ques_text" => 1}, limit: 1]`?

Comment: @Dogbert. It works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`projection` should be a map with the key being the field name and the value being one of those specified [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#find-projection). In this case, you probably want:

```
projection: %{"ques_text" => 1}
```

This will select only the `ques_text` field in each document.